# openssl_encrypt & decrypt reducing quality of webm video

Tags: php, encryption, webm

I have a simple microsite where a user records a video of themselves using the built-in JS MediaRecorder (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) and it gets encrypted using openssl_encrypt.

When they want to share/view that video, it's decrypted using openssl_decrypt.

The problem is, once it comes out the decrypt function the quality has reduced to the point you see artifacts. WebM videos are still watchable, but MP4 videos (captured from iPhone) are unwatchable - the video has 1FPS... What could be causing this dramatic drop in quality?

The solution was working perfectly until we implemented this encryption.

We pass the recorded file into it directly.

```php
encryptFile($_FILES["file"]['tmp_name'], $dir . $filename, 'secret-key');
decryptFile("videos/" . $id . "." . $mime, $decrypted_video, 'secret-key');
```

encryptFile();

```php
/**
 * @param  $source  Path of the unencrypted file
 * @param  $dest  Path of the encrypted file to created
 * @param  $key  Encryption key
 */
function encryptFile($source, $dest, $key)
{

        $cipher = 'aes-256-cbc';
        $ivLenght = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
        $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivLenght);
    
        $fpSource = fopen($source, 'rb');
        $fpDest = fopen($dest, 'w');
    
        fwrite($fpDest, $iv);
    
        while (!feof($fpSource)) {
            $plaintext = fread($fpSource, $ivLenght * FILE_ENCRYPTION_BLOCKS);
            $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
            $iv = substr($ciphertext, 0, $ivLenght);
    
            fwrite($fpDest, $ciphertext);
        }
    
        fclose($fpSource);
        fclose($fpDest);
}
```

decryptFile();

```php
/**
 * @param  $source  Path of the encrypted file
 * @param  $dest  Path of the decrypted file
 * @param  $key  Encryption key
 */
function decryptFile($source, $dest, $key)
{
    $cipher = 'aes-256-cbc';
    $ivLenght = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);

    $fpSource = fopen($source, 'rb');
    $fpDest = fopen($dest, 'w');

    $iv = fread($fpSource, $ivLenght);

    while (!feof($fpSource)) {
        $ciphertext = fread($fpSource, $ivLenght * (FILE_ENCRYPTION_BLOCKS + 1));
        $plaintext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, $cipher, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
        $iv = substr($plaintext, 0, $ivLenght);

        fwrite($fpDest, $plaintext);
    }

    fclose($fpSource);
    fclose($fpDest);
}
```

Comment: This seems extremely unlikely. Try a very simple test: Take a file, run it through an encrypt/decrypt cycle, and compare the two. Same exact number of bytes? Same `md5sum` checksums? If not, something more than encryption/decryption is happening in your process. If they're the same, something else is going on. Are you trying to stream the decrypted data right to the user? If so, perhaps it's just slow, and 1 FPS is just how fast the encryption is proceeding.

Comment: I've just increased the number for FILE_ENCRYPTION_BLOCKS from 1000 to 10000and it seems to have resolved the issue (for webm at least). It's still an issue for iphones/mp4 recordings, but it's definitely improved the quality. What's best practice for the number of encryption blocks?

Comment: `FILE_ENCRYPTION_BLOCKS` might change how *fast* encryption/decryption processes, but it will not change the file *quality*. Again: are you streaming the result live to the user, perhaps?

Comment: I am yes - is this the issue?

Comment: Though to elaborate, I wait until the file is decrypted before streaming.

Comment: To make it clear, it's physically impossible that OpenSSL knows how to re-encode video to reduce its quality, not more than it can translate dialogues into French. What can be happening is that it's corrupting the binary stream, but not enough to make it unrecognisable as video codec by a media player. Probably, it's damaging or omitting some fragments and leaving others untouched.

Comment: not sure if this working for you or not! i had same issue but in PDF, i change $cipher from aes-256-cbc to idea-cbc and increased FILE_ENCRYPTION_BLOCKS

Answer (score 3):

Decryption is not consistent with encryption and determines a wrong IV.

The wrong IVs cause the first block in each decrypted plaintext chunk to be corrupted. The larger the chunksize i.e. the fewer chunks the fewer errors, which explains the improvement when increasing `FILE_ENCRYPTION_BLOCKS`.

For encryption and decryption to be consistent, it must be in `decryptFile()`:

```php
$iv = substr($ciphertext, 0, $ivLenght);
```

With this change, decryption works.

---

The code would be more robust if the logic mimicked CBC mode for the data as a whole so that decryption were possible without knowing the chunk size (i.e. encryption and decryption can use different chunk sizes). To achieve this:

- only the last plaintext chunk must be padded (currently: all chunks are padded). Fix (on the example for encryption, analogously for decryption):

  ```php
  if (!feof($fpSource)) {
      $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv); // don't pad 
  } else {
      $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv); // pad
  }
  ```
- the last block of the previous ciphertext chunk must be used as IV ( currently: the first block is used). Fix:

  ```php
  $iv = substr($ciphertext, -$ivLenght);
  ```

An alternative to avoid padding at all is to use a stream cipher mode like CTR (however, this requires a different determination of the IV, as the IV handling of both modes differs).

Comment: [Here](https://replit.com/@3hK8cL8H24hwiS7/FirstLustrousEngineers#main.php) you can verify online that your code works with the fix (using an approx. 17 MB .mp4 file as an example). [Here](https://replit.com/@3hK8cL8H24hwiS7/RedSlategrayChapter#main.php) you can find an optimization of your code with my recommendations from the last section.

Comment: Encrypt/Decrypt class probably from: https://medium.com/@antoine.lame/how-to-encrypt-files-with-php-f4adead297de

Answer (score 1):

OK, I got nerd-sniped by this question and dove in pretty deep.

The summary is that:

1. If you want your code to encrypt/decrypt *entirely within the scope of your own code, and with a fixed `FILE_ENCRYPTION_BLOCKS` value*, then the IV fix in @Topaco's answer will likely suffice. Otherwise you will need to apply the rest of the suggested fixes.
2. Changing `FILE_ENCRYPTION_BLOCKS` in your existing code likely just moves the compatibility breakage further down the line, possibly past the end of the file, at which point there's not really any point in streaming encryption code anyway.
3. If you want your code to produce output compatible with OpenSSL and other libs then... *here be dragons*...

The simplest answer would be to use an existing library that already does this, and does it well. Namely: [jeskew/php-encrypted-streams](https://github.com/jeskew/php-encrypted-streams), which I heavily referrenced to in making my own code work after I hit a wall with it.

The more complex answer is:

- The block size is not necessarily the same as the IV size, and it's kind of a kludge to detect.
- The IV for the next block is the *last* `$iv_size` bytes of the previous block.
- All but the final block need `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING.

```php
//define('DEBUG', true);
function debug(...$args) {
    if( defined('DEBUG') && DEBUG === true ) {
        printf(...$args);
    }
}

if( ! function_exists('openssl_cipher_block_length') ) {
    function openssl_cipher_block_length($cipher) {
        return strlen(openssl_encrypt(
            "\x00", $cipher, "", OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, str_repeat("\x00", openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher))
        ));
    }
}

function openssl_encrypt_stream($stream_in, $stream_out, $key, $iv, $cipher, $block_multiplier=256) {
    $cipher_block_length = openssl_cipher_block_length($cipher);
    $buffer_size = $cipher_block_length * $block_multiplier;
    $iv_size = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);

    debug("Cipher: %s, Block Size: %d, IV Size: %d, Block Multiplier: %d\n", $cipher, $cipher_block_length, $iv_size, $block_multiplier);

    while( ! feof($stream_in) ) {
        $buffer = fread($stream_in, $buffer_size);
        debug("Plaintext Buffer Length: %d, Content: %s\n", strlen($buffer), bin2hex($buffer));

        $options = OPENSSL_RAW_DATA;
        if( feof($stream_in) ) {
            debug("Final block.\n");
        } else {
            $options |= OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING;
        }
        $e_buffer = openssl_encrypt($buffer, $cipher, $key, $options, $iv);

        debug("IV: %s, Ciphertext: %s\n", bin2hex($iv), bin2hex($e_buffer));

        if( $e_buffer === false ) {
            throw new \Exception(openssl_error_string());
        }

        $iv = substr($e_buffer, -1 * $cipher_block_length);
        fwrite($stream_out, $e_buffer);
        debug(PHP_EOL);
    }
}

function openssl_decrypt_stream($stream_in, $stream_out, $key, $iv, $cipher, $block_multiplier=256) {
    $cipher_block_length = openssl_cipher_block_length($cipher);
    $buffer_size = $cipher_block_length * $block_multiplier;
    $iv_size = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);

    debug("Cipher: %s, Block Size: %d, IV Size: %d, Block Multiplier: %d\n", $cipher, $cipher_block_length, $iv_size, $block_multiplier);

    $next_buffer = fread($stream_in, $buffer_size);
    do {
        $buffer = $next_buffer;
        $next_buffer = fread($stream_in, $buffer_size);
        debug("Ciphertext Buffer Length: %d, Content: %s\n", strlen($buffer), bin2hex($buffer));

        $options = OPENSSL_RAW_DATA;
        if( feof($stream_in) && $next_buffer === '' ) {
            debug("Final block.\n");
        } else {
            $options |= OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING;
        }
        $p_buffer = openssl_decrypt($buffer, $cipher, $key, $options, $iv);

        debug("IV: %s, Plaintext: %s\n", bin2hex($iv), bin2hex($p_buffer));

        if( $p_buffer === false ) {
            throw new \Exception(openssl_error_string());
        }

        $iv = substr($buffer, -1 * $cipher_block_length);
        fwrite($stream_out, $p_buffer);
        debug(PHP_EOL);
    } while( !( feof($stream_in) && $next_buffer === '') );
}
```

Testing code:

```php
// encrypt/decrypt normally as a control
function e_control($file, $key, $iv, $cipher) {
    $begin = hrtime(true);
    $enc = openssl_encrypt(file_get_contents($file), $cipher, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    $dur = hrtime(true) - $begin;
    return [ $enc, $dur ];
}

function d_control($enc, $key, $iv, $cipher) {
    $begin = hrtime(true);
    $plain = openssl_decrypt($enc, $cipher, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    $dur = hrtime(true) - $begin;
    return [ $plain, $dur ];
}

// encrypt test
function e_test($file, $key, $iv, $cipher, $block_multiplier=256) {
    $stream_out = fopen('php://memory', 'rwb');

    $begin = hrtime(true);
    $stream_in  = fopen($file, 'rb'); // fairness with control
    openssl_encrypt_stream($stream_in, $stream_out, $key, $iv, $cipher, $block_multiplier);
    $dur = hrtime(true) - $begin;

    fclose($stream_in);
    rewind($stream_out);
    return [ stream_get_contents($stream_out), $dur ];
}

// decrypt test
function d_test($enc, $key, $iv, $cipher, $block_multiplier=256) {
    $stream_in  = fopen('php://memory', 'rwb');
    $stream_out = fopen('php://memory', 'rwb');
    fwrite($stream_in, $enc);
    rewind($stream_in);

    $begin = hrtime(true);
    openssl_decrypt_stream($stream_in, $stream_out, $key, $iv, $cipher, $block_multiplier);
    $dur = hrtime(true) - $begin;

    fclose($stream_in);
    rewind($stream_out);
    return [ stream_get_contents($stream_out), $dur ];
}

// dd if=/dev/random of=./test.bin bs=1024 count=10240
$file   = 'test.bin';
$cipher = 'aes-256-cbc';
$key    = str_repeat("\x00", 32);
$iv     = str_repeat("\x00", openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher));
$mult   = 256;

// warm the FS cache for fairness
file_get_contents($file);

list($c, $c_dur) = e_control( $file, $key, $iv, $cipher);
list($e, $e_dur) = e_test(    $file, $key, $iv, $cipher, $mult);
list($x, $x_dur) = d_control( $c,    $key, $iv, $cipher);
list($d, $d_dur) = d_test(    $c,    $key, $iv, $cipher, $mult);

printf("Control - Hash: %s, Duration: %0.3f ms\n", md5($c), $c_dur / 1000000);
printf("Encrypt - Hash: %s, Duration: %0.3f ms\n", md5($e), $e_dur / 1000000);
printf("Control - Hash: %s, Duration: %0.3f ms\n", md5($x), $x_dur / 1000000);
printf("Decrypt - Hash: %s, Duration: %0.3f ms\n", md5($d), $d_dur / 1000000);
```

Example Output:

```
Control - Hash: 5f5db49554de8fa6a7195c4d0cbc0ad8, Duration: 30.788 ms
Encrypt - Hash: 5f5db49554de8fa6a7195c4d0cbc0ad8, Duration: 75.244 ms
Control - Hash: 8eee2cf0ee0444cafa9280a89821f1ff, Duration: 9.054 ms
Decrypt - Hash: 8eee2cf0ee0444cafa9280a89821f1ff, Duration: 61.600 ms
```

It's worth noting that while `$cipher` in this code *seems* configurable, this methodology will only work with ciphers in CBC mode, and probably only AES at that. The jeskew/php-encrypted-streams lib linked above implements a wider range of cipher modes, but still only AES.

Comment: @Topaco I guess I just laser-focused on the line of code in your answer and didn't fully read the rest of the text. <_<;